# Why can't I connect to this SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are having issues with our SQL Server. About two times a day we have to restart our server because SQL becomes unresponsive to our web applications.
It doesn't look like we have a problem with to many connections, as there are never more then 20 active at a time.

The weird thing is I can access SQL from MS SQL Enterprise Manager 8.0 only. Connections from any other application (ASP.NET or SQL Server Management Studio 05) time-out.

Queries work fine in Enterprise Manager, so I don't think it's an issue with locks either.

Comment: It happens randomly and can happen more or less then twice a day.

Comment: This is a MS SQL 8.0 server. Its the only application that runs on the server.
Its the connection that times out, not the querys.
Enterprise manager is the only app that can create a new connection.
Everyone else has the same problem connection from their desktop when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SQL Server log is clean AND (you can connect to DB locally OR remotely) AND a reboot restores your app to a known state then it suggests a pooling problem and/or network problem

We had a similar problem that was fixed for no stated reason by upgrading to latest service pack. Our problem manifested itself in the box keeping the underlying network connections open while the web app thought they were closed, so it would try to reinstate the pool and then run into max connections. Your question states you have not hit max connections but your symptoms are similar. Take a look at the network connections from the OS level.

Can you connect from the same box that hosts your web apps, but using another client app, like Query Analyzer or even bcp or isql from the command line?

Another thing to wonder: if you are able to connect from a web app box, can you USE the db your app uses? If so can you do things once you are in there?

What are the parameter settings for connection pool of web app? Have you tried adjusting these?

Answer (score 1):

- Any environment changes, hardware or software?
- What was the last change?

Just a note from experience on network issues.. if network is failing, it can cause a build up of network connections, which you would only be able to see from performance counter in performance monitor (perfmon), so that would be the place that I'd look.

If there are no environment changes, perhaps the database needs some good ol' maintenance, like consolidating tables and indexes, pushing logs to backup or purging them, and whatever DBA's do to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with MySQL previously where idle connections would get marked as stale and would time out and eventually I had to restart the application.
Perhaps there is a configuration on your connection pool that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

If SQL server itself sits idle and no blocking is noticed, then could be some network or firewall or antivirus issues. Or just a server RAID array is dying.

Answer (score -1):

What happening whit RAM memory in that time.
Maybe you ruining out with RAM